# How to deal with prefix schema in unit test?

Tags: java, sql, h2

In java code the common legacy code will have different schemas depends on the usage.

```
public summary getTicketInfo(Cust id) {
...
String q = "SELECT name, address, price, contact FROM USER_DBA.CUSTOMER WHERE id = ?";
...
}
```

So during unit testing does anyone ever come across of those schema prefixes? How do you deal with them?
If I were use another database and define my own schema CUSTOMER without the prefix USER_DBA. , TEST_DBA, ADMIN_DBA. etc how would I call the actual method that has those prefix attached?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking.  What is switching the schemas out? is that not accounted for in the method?  what exactly are you unit testing?  the creation of a string?  or the db connection itself?  if the latter, that sounds more like an integration test over a unit test.

Comment: I would want to test the method getTicketInfo, but either way prefix of the schema is causing errors when  I define my own table as customer. I was wondering if there is a way to get around the prefixes

Comment: I don't understand the question, but did you have a look at [`set schema_search_path`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_schema_search_path)?